# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following code with redux-toolkit but i can't find the error

```
if (token) { // this code dispatches the function below in a different file
  const data = {
    service: 'stripe',
    stripe_payment_id: token.id,
  };
  dispatch(setPaymentMethod({ data, tenantId: tenant.id }));
}

export const setPaymentMethod = (params: any) => {
  const { data, tenantId } = params;
  return async (dispatch: any, getState: any) =>
    dispatch(
      postRequest(
        `${API.TENANTS}/${tenantId}/${API.PAYMENT_METHODS}`,
        data,
        response => console.log(response),
      ),
    );
};
```

The code above calls the API handler file like this

```
const postRequest = async (
  url: string,
  body: any,
  onSuccess: (x: any) => void,
  onError?: () => void,
  params?: any,
) => {
  return async (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
    try {
      let response = await API.post(url, body, {});
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response);
        onSuccess(response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Maybe I am not seeing the error and it seems easy to fix but haven't found the solution, please help!

I am using redux-toolkit which uses redux-thunk behind the scenes already

/Store config

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  /* PLOP_INJECT_EXPORT */
  tenantsReducer: tenantsSlice,
  receiptsReducer: receiptsSlice,
  geoLocationReducer: geoLocationSlice,
  storesReducer: storesSlice,
  authReducer: authSlice,
  exampleReducer: exampleSlice,
  uiReducer: uiSlice,
  tokensReducer: tokensSlice,
  [usersApi.reducerPath]: usersApi.reducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  version: 1,
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  // whitelist: ['uiReducer'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

Comment: How did you create the store? Show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 code added

Answer (score 0):

Redux-Thunk doesn't handle promises out of the book. Check [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).